# Why use It.is<> or It.IsAny<> if I could just define a variable?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, mocking, moq

Hi I've been using moq for a while when I see this code.

I have to setup a return in one of my repo.

```
 mockIRole.Setup(r => r.GetSomething(It.IsAny<Guid>(), It.IsAny<Guid>(), 
                  It.IsAny<Guid>())).Returns(ReturnSomething);
```

I have three parameters and I just saw these in one of articles or blog on the net.

What is the use of `It.Is<>` or `It.IsAny<>` for an object? if I could use `Guid.NewGuid()` or other types then why use `It.Is`?

I'm sorry I'm not sure if my question is right or am I missing some knowledge in testing.
But it seems like there is nothing wrong either way.

Comment: `It.IsAny<Guid>()` means that you don't care what parameter was passed. `Guid.NewGuid()` means that you want to setup the method to return something only if the first parameter is equal to this new GUID.

Comment: I don't know what you are asking.  Moq is saying that, as long as the pass the correct types in, the call is valid and should return your object.

Comment: `It.Is<>` is useful to ensure you are calling your dependency with the correct values in the arguments

Comment: I've seen junior devs trying to use `It.IsAny<int>()` to generate variables for test cases. It doesn't work :) I've also seen a lot of lazy test writers use `It.IsAny` for everything because they can't be arsed to figure out the actual variables to use..

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Using `It.IsAny<>`, `It.Is<>`, or a variable all serve different purposes.  They provide increasingly specific ways to match a parameter when setting up or verifying a method.

### It.IsAny

The method set up with `It.IsAny<>` will match *any* parameter you give to the method.  So, in your example, the following invocations would all return the same thing (`ReturnSomething`):

```
role.GetSomething(Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid());

Guid sameGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
role.GetSomething(sameGuid, sameGuid, sameGuid);

role.GetSomething(Guid.Empty, Guid.NewGuid(), sameGuid);
```

It doesn't matter the actual value of the `Guid` that was passed.

### It.Is

The `It.Is<>` construct is useful for setup or verification of a method, letting you specify a function that will match the argument.  For instance:

```
Guid expectedGuid = ...
mockIRole.Setup(r => r.GetSomething(
                 It.Is<Guid>(g => g.ToString().StartsWith("4")), 
                 It.Is<Guid>(g => g != Guid.Empty), 
                 It.Is<Guid>(g => g == expectedGuid)))
         .Returns(ReturnSomething);
```

This allows you to restrict the value more than just any value, but permits you to be lenient in what you accept.

### Defining a Variable

When you set up (or verify) a method parameter with a variable, you're saying you want *exactly* that value.  A method called with another value will never match your setup/verify.

```
Guid expectedGuids = new [] { Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid() };
mockIRole.Setup(r => r.GetSomething(expectedGuids[0], expectedGuids[1], expectedGuids[2]))
         .Returns(ReturnSomething);
```

Now there's exactly one case where `GetSomething` will return `ReturnSomething`: when all `Guid`s match the expected values that you set it up with.

Comment: This is really what I need. I thought defining and using is really a different thing. It just that it.is are flexible to accept parameters.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful, will add to the documentation regarding Mock.

Comment: Hi Patrick, in relation to your answer would you be so kind to explain to me further my problem in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52854915/how-to-create-a-unit-test-for-adding-items-in-a-repository/52856751? Initially I passed a variable to my Verify method and it failed. However, when I changed it and passed an It.IsAny<T> instead it passed. I am new to unit testing so I am still struggling to understand this.

Answer (score 13):

If you look at the [Quickstart documentation for Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#matching-arguments)

**Matching Arguments**

```
// any value
mock.Setup(foo => foo.DoSomething(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(true);


// matching Func<int>, lazy evaluated
mock.Setup(foo => foo.Add(It.Is<int>(i => i % 2 == 0))).Returns(true); 


// matching ranges
mock.Setup(foo => foo.Add(It.IsInRange<int>(0, 10, Range.Inclusive))).Returns(true); 


// matching regex
mock.Setup(x => x.DoSomething(It.IsRegex("[a-d]+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))).Returns("foo");
```

Comment: What if we don't care about *any* param passed in?  Imagine a method with four or more params, it get's pretty long.