# How to Create a Unit Test for Adding Items in a Repository?

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

I have an **IUnitOfWork** interface that encapsulates my custom repositories. My custom repositories in turn inherit from an **IRepository** interface.

```
// The class that I am attempting to unit test
// EmployeeBusiness.cs
private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

public EmployeeBusiness(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
{
    _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
}


public EmployeeDto AddEmployee(EmployeeDto employeeDto)
{
    var employee = Mapper.Map<Employee>(employeeDto);

    if (employee == null) return null;

    _unitOfWork.Employees
        .Add(employee);

    _unitOfWork.Complete();

    return Mapper.Map<EmployeeDto>(employee); 
}

// IUnitOfWork interface
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    IEmployeeRepository Employees { get; }

    void Complete();
}

// IEmployeeRepository interface
public interface IEmployeeRepository : IRepository<Employee> { }

// IRepository<T> interface
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    void Add(TEntity entity);

    // I have added other methods for simplicity
}
```

I am struggling with unit testing the `AddEmployee()` method because I am getting this error:

*Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: uow => uow.Employees.Add(Employee)
Configured setups: 
IUnitOfWork uow => uow.Employees.Add(Employee)
Performed invocations: 
IRepository`1.Add(Employee)*

This is my unit test

```
[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    _employeeDto = new EmployeeDto
    {
        FirstName = "John",
        LastName = "Smith",
        BirthDate = new DateTime(1965, 12, 31)
    };

    _employee = new Employee
    {
       FirstName = "John",
       LastName = "Smith",
       BirthDate = new DateTime(1965, 12, 31)
    };

    _unitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();

    Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddProfile<EmployeeProfile>();
    });
}


[Test]
public void AddEmployee_WhenCalled_AddEmployeeToDatabase()
{
    _unitOfWork.Setup(uow => uow.Employees.Add(_employee));
    _employeeBusiness = new EmployeeBusiness(_unitOfWork.Object);

    _employeeBusiness.AddEmployee(_employeeDto);

    _unitOfWork.Verify(uow => uow.Employees.Add(_employee), Times.Once);
    _unitOfWork.Verify(uow => uow.Complete(), Times.Once);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to get it to work by changing my unit test

```
[Test]
public void AddEmployee_WhenCalled_AddEmployeeToDatabase()
{
    _unitOfWork.Setup(uow => uow.Employees.Add(_employee));
    _employeeBusiness = new EmployeeBusiness(_unitOfWork.Object);

    var result = _employeeBusiness.AddEmployee(_employeeDto);

    //_unitOfWork.Verify(uow => uow.Employees.Add(_employee), Times.Once); <-- This did not work 

    _unitOfWork.Verify(uow => uow.Employees.Add(It.IsAny<Employee>()), Times.Once); // <-- After changing this to It.IsAny<Employee>() it worked 
    _unitOfWork.Verify(uow => uow.Complete(), Times.Once);
}
```

Can anyone please help me understand the difference of using `It.IsAny<Employee>()` as opposed to the `_employee` variable?

---

**UPDATE**

The explanation can be found at [Thorin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52857431/6435817).

Comment: Moq says: "This class *(It class)* allows the setup to match a method invocation with an arbitrary value, with a value in a specified range, or even one that matches a given predicate." This means that we should only use methods like `It.IsAny<T>()` inside of `.Setup()`.

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to say that we should only use methods like It.IsAny<T>() inside of .Setup(). It really depends on the nature of what you're aiming to test. I agree that in many cases It.Is<T>() is a more appropriate choice, but I wouldn't say IsAny should only be used inside of .Setup().

Answer (score 3):

The reason the test you provided in your answer (copied below) passes when your original fails is because your original was expecting the mock to be called with the specific reference variable you're using (in this case _employee). Perhaps you were expecting Moq and .Verify() to check for equality using .equals() instead of ==?

In the context of your method under test, this is correct and desirable - based on the name of the test you're just looking to test that the method does in fact map your input to an Employee and calls the repository's add method. If you want to make sure that data wasn't lost in the mapping, you could use It.Is(), which takes a function you can use to assert qualities of the input (such as the name matching your expected value).

If you're aiming just to test that the mapping succeeded, you may be interested in [Automapper Configuration Validation](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration-validation.html)  as a separate test.

```
[Test]
public void AddEmployee_WhenCalled_AddEmployeeToDatabase()
{
    _unitOfWork.Setup(uow => uow.Employees.Add(_employee));
    _employeeBusiness = new EmployeeBusiness(_unitOfWork.Object);

    var result = _employeeBusiness.AddEmployee(_employeeDto);

    //_unitOfWork.Verify(uow => uow.Employees.Add(_employee), Times.Once); <-- This did not work 

    _unitOfWork.Verify(uow => uow.Employees.Add(It.IsAny<Employee>()), Times.Once); // <-- After changing this to It.IsAny<Employee>() it worked 
    _unitOfWork.Verify(uow => uow.Complete(), Times.Once);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, it helped clarify a lot of things. I just noticed that you mentioned the word **reference variable**. So you're saying that the `_employee` variable was passed as a reference and not as a value?

Comment: That's correct - assuming Employee is a class rather than a struct, it's a reference type and was passed by reference. So when you did your verify call, it checked to see whether the reference that was used in the invocation was the same as the reference you expected, rather than whether the values were equivalent. [Here's a good deep-dive](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3043992/application-development/a-deep-dive-value-and-reference-types-in-net.html) on value vs reference types if it will help you.

Answer (score -2):

You aren't checking the return value of `AddEmployee`.

```
[Test]
public void AddEmployee_WhenCalled_AddEmployeeToDatabase()
{
    _unitOfWork.Setup(uow => uow.Employees.Add(_employee));
    _employeeBusiness = new EmployeeBusiness(_unitOfWork.Object);

    var result = _employeeBusiness.AddEmployee(_employeeDto);

    Assert.IsNotNull(result); // <---

    _unitOfWork.Verify(uow => uow.Employees.Add(_employee), Times.Once);
    _unitOfWork.Verify(uow => uow.Complete(), Times.Once);
}
```

Comment: Even adding that did not solve the issue since the error has something to do with the performed invocation of `_employeeBusiness.AddEmployee()`. It is IRepository.Add() which I don't understand since my assertion is `_unitOfWork.Verify(uow => uow.Employees.Add(_employee));`

Comment: This is not correct - it is the first _verify that is failing, due to expecting a reference variable that is not provided to the mock. Adding the Assert not null will not harm the test but it will still fail when it hits the first verify.